# How to refresh playlist in Noise music app?

Tags: music

I have added some songs in the Music directory and renamed some existing files. I don't see any button to refresh playlist on the Music app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no need of `Refresh` button for `Noise`. When I renamed a file, the Music folder is imported automatically to Noise app. If not, importing that folder to the library again will do the trick.